How to Prevent Flickering When Moving a Mesh with Autodesk.Viewing.ModelBuilder?
I am using the Autodesk.Viewing.ModelBuilder to add a custom mesh to the Forge Viewer. I want to move the mesh dynamically using a slider by updating its position matrix and calling Builder.updateMesh().
My code updates the mesh's matrix and then calls Builder.updateMesh() each time the slider value changes. This successfully moves the mesh, but it causes the viewer to flicker with each update:
this.EditMesh.mesh.position.x += 1; 
this.EditMesh.mesh.updateMatrix();
this.EditMesh.mesh.updateMatrixWorld(true);
this._ModelBuilder.updateMesh(this.EditMesh.mesh, false, false);

If I do not call Builder.updateMesh(), the mesh does not move, but the viewer does not flicker.
The highlight functionality (used for selection) and the explode feature of Autodesk Viewer move objects smoothly without flickering, suggesting there might be a way to achieve smooth movement without the flicker.
Is there a way to move a mesh smoothly without calling Builder.updateMesh() on every slider change?
Alternatively, is there a way to prevent the flickering when using Builder.updateMesh()?
